# Add objects from database to a List, using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table `books` and i want to put all of its contents into a `List<book>` (right now i'am stuck at adding a single element).
I tried

```
public class DataContext
{
    LINQtoSQLDataContext db = new LINQtoSQLDataContext();
    List<book> books = new List<book>();
    public List<book> addBook()
    {
        books.Add((book)from book in db.books where book.bookID == 1 select book);
        return books;
    }
}
```

But when i try to set it as the source of my wpf dataGrid, it throws an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[DataLayer.book]' to type 'DataLayer.book'.

So the question is, how do i properly convert data from the database to a list?

Comment: 'Where' will return an array. You only want to add 1 item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the List of book as below:

```cs
public List<book> addBook()
{
    return (from book in db.books 
        where book.bookID == 1 
        select book)
        .ToList();
}
```

And it's weird to name the method `addBook` as the method's outcome is to return a list of book.

Name it as: `public List<book> GetBooks()`

While [`List<T>.Add(T)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=net-6.0) only allow to add **single** item to list, to add **multiple** items into list, you need [`List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-6.0).

Comment: You're completely right about that method name. I was just testing how these things work, and forgot to change. I won't edit the post however, as it would invalidate some of the replies.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your problem correctly, the solution is simpler than expected, try making a where condition like this:

```
public class DataContext
{
LINQtoSQLDataContext db = new LINQtoSQLDataContext();
List<book> books = new List<book>();
public List<book> addBook()
{
    books = db.book.Where(x => x.bookId == 1).ToList();
    return books;
} 
}
```

Comment: This doesnt add the book, it overwrites any existing books in the list

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood, I saw that you have solved it so good continuation!

Comment: Well as it seems the question was wrong and your answer is what OP was looking for. so my bad!

Answer (score 1):

Just as sr28 pointed out, this will return an array. You could either add the array to the `books` list. I personally prefer using the method syntax.

I don't really understand why you would add the book to this list. But here you go. Since you already defined `books` you dont need to return it, you can simply add `book` to `books`.

```
public void AddBook()
{
    var book = db.books.FirstOrDefault(b => b.BookId == 1);
    books.add(book);
}
```